# Sample code using Core-Plot for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-plot, graphing

I'm trying to find some sample code for Core-Plot on the iPhone.  So far, all the examples I've found plot equations such as X^2 or 1/X, etc. over some range.  My goal is to find some sample code that just plots two points ((1,2) and (2,3), for example) and connects them with a line.

It seems simple, but I've yet to find out how to approach this.  I've checked the Core-Plot Wiki, and am again only able to find more complex examples.

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the examples included with Core Plot? There's a mix of Mac and iOS apps. Except for the hosting view, the API is identical on both platforms.

Comment: Thanks -- I have but for some reason having a lot of trouble understanding it.  Would love to just display an empty graph in as few lines as possible, then I'll try to build off that.

Comment: The "Axis Demo" in the Mac CPTTestApp and in the Plot Gallery app both show empty axes with no plots. It also shows some extra stuff like grid lines, log scales, and background bands.